# Свойства pubDate

Tags: c#

Решил вытянуть новости с определённой темы форума, что не составило труда. Но возник вопрос, как изменить свойство pubDate на 24х часовой формат. В данный момент каждая тема имеет вид `12/3/2017 2:57:55 PM`. А хотелось бы `12/3/2017 14:57:55`. Либо можно так `03/12/2017`.

Как можно поправить код?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Classes;

namespace controls
{
    public partial class News : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.PopulateRssFeed();
        }

        private void PopulateRssFeed()
        {
            string RssFeedUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RssFeedUrl"];
            string RssMaxNews = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RssMaxNews"];

            List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
            try
            {
                XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
                xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
                var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                             select new
                             {
                                 title = x.Element("title").Value,
                                 link = x.Element("link").Value,
                                 pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                                 description = x.Element("description").Value,
                             }).Take(10).ToList();
                if (items != null)
                {
                    foreach (var i in items)
                    {
                        Feeds f = new Feeds
                        {
                            Title = i.title,
                            Link = i.link,
                            PublishDate = i.pubDate,
                            Description = i.description
                        };

                        feeds.Add(f);
                    }
                }

                gvRss.DataSource = feeds;
                gvRss.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: RSS? Почему бы не использовать [SyndicationFeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: RSS)). Я наткнулся на решение с помощью класса DateTime.ParseExact, но к сожалению пока не могу понять как подружить его с текущим кодом. Так как C# начал осваивать совсем недавно. Думаю что с SyndicationFeed будет тоже самое. Спасибо за статью, сейчас ознакомлюсь.

Comment: Товарищи. Что-то не могу я разобраться. Может кто помочь, или поделиться куском аналогичного кода?

Comment: Не задавайте вопрос в комментариях - его никто не увидит (мне пришло сообщение только потому, что я раньше отписывался в комментах). Отредактируйте вопрос, тогда он поднимется на главную страницу ru.so - его все увидят.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("12/3/2017 2:57:55 PM")` разве не работает?

Comment: var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
      select new
      {
           title = x.Element("title").Value,
           link = x.Element("link").Value,
           pubDate = DateTime.Parse("12/3/2017 2:57:55 PM"),
           description = x.Element("description").Value,
       }).Take(10).ToList();        
Если так, то получаем само собой одну и ту же дату во всех новостях. Не бейте палками, если что не так. Просто C# только осваиваю. В C++ с этим не сталкивался.

Comment: `pubDate = DateTime.Parse(x.Element("pubDate").Value)`

Comment: Тогда мы возвращаемся к нашим баранам) 12/4/2017 2:34:57 PM